# php get array's data size

Tags: php, arrays, size

Having this array:

```
Array
(
    [_block1] => Array
        (
            [list] => Array
            (
                 [sub-list] => Array
                 (
                 )
            )
            [links] => Number
            [total] => Number
            ...
        )
    [_block2] => Array
        (
             [@attributes] => Array
             (
             )
             [title] => ...
             [data] => Array ()
             ...
        )
    [_block3] => Array
        (
             ..
        )
)
```

Those blocks contain data returned by api. Knowing that each api returns data in a different way/structure I need to measure/calculate the data/size inside of each and one of them and then do `if data >  X` or < do something.

Is it possible? I have searched google but I only found `count()` and that isn't what I need to make this work.

**Edit:**
Each and of the those blocks contain many other sub blocks, and I was thinking of calculating the data size in bytes, because count wont do the job here.

Comment: What unit of measurement are you trying to get? Words, characters, bytes?

Comment: How do you define the *size* of your data?

Comment: bytes... that's what I was having in mind...

Comment: It looks like this is the result of a XML parser. If so the parser itself has methods to get the size. Can you specify the origin of this structure ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understood well your question, you need the size of each "block" subarray inside the main array.

You can do something like this:

```
$sizes = array();
foreach($returnedArray as $key => $content) {
    $sizes[$key] = count($content);
}
```

The `$sizes` array will be an associative array which the various "block"s as keys and the size of the data as values.

Edit:
after the edit of the question, if the data inside the innermost arrays are strings or integers you can use a function like this:

```
function getSize($arr) {
    $tot = 0;
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            $tot += getSize($a);
        }
        if (is_string($a)) {
            $tot += strlen($a);
        }
        if (is_int($a)) {
            $tot += PHP_INT_SIZE;
        }
    }
    return $tot;
}
```

assuming to have only ASCII-encoded strings.

Comment: check code edit... this won't do it because of the structure that api's response

Comment: What does the data inside the most inner array is? Strings and integers?

Comment: all kinds, integers/strings/booleans

Comment: why the $getSize($a).... what is its purpose because right now it returns an error

Comment: My mistake, the $ character is obviously wrong. I'm editing the answer to fix it.

Comment: your missing a `)` at first if

Comment: Thanks, corrected. I wrote the function without testing it, and my fingers always betray me :)

Comment: well it's same thing as @SERPRO's response but for now I think I am going to use it because at least now I now each `block`'s empty value... It's not what I am looking for but it's a work around. Thank you

Answer (score 33):

```
echo  mb_strlen(serialize((array)$arr), '8bit');
```

Comment: No additional info given, but a nice one-liner. Although it also counts brackets, commas and quotation marks.

Comment: nice solution, you can use just `strlen()` instead of `mb_strlen()`, because strlen() iterates byte-by-byte in string.

Comment: nice solution if we want just know the length of array, but its so bad if we need that for performance enhancement

Answer (score 6):

To get the size in bytes you can use the below code.

```
$serialized = serialize($foo);
if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
    $size = mb_strlen($serialized, '8bit');
} else {
    $size = strlen($serialized);
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$x = 32;
foreach($blocks as $key => $block)
{
  if(getArraySize($block) < $x)
  {
     //Do Something
  }else
  {
     //Do another thing
  }
}


//Recursive function
function getArraySize($array)
{
   $size = 0;
   foreach($array as $element)
   {
      if(is_array($element))
         $size += getArraySize($element);
      else
         $size += strlen($element);
   }

   return $size;
}
```

Comment: check code edit... this won't do it because of the structure that api's response

Comment: @w0rldart see my edited answer to see if it fit now in your requirements.

Comment: nice function but won't do it... the only thing I see possible to it exists a way of returning the bytes size of the array

Comment: @w0rldart strlen will return the number of bytes, unless the text has multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

Get array size in bytes:

```
<?php
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$json = json_encode($array); // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT for multiline json formatting
echo mb_strlen($json, '8bit') . " bytes\n"; // output - 7 bytes

// for multidimensional array
$array = [['a','b','c'], ['e','f','g']];
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT for multiline json formatting
echo mb_strlen($json, '8bit') . " bytes\n"; // output - 61 bytes
```