# Tabular form do not show all the values inserted in textbox why? post array do not have all values why?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, datatable

The problem is i am dealing with a multidimensional array. Let me explain the problem to you with simple example:
Consider a table like :

```
<form method="post" id="f">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
    <tbody>
      <?php for ($a = 0; $a <= 101; $a++) { ?>

           <tr>

          <?php for ($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++) { ?>

   <td><input type="text" name="columnVal<?php echo $b; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $a . '-' . $b; ?>" /></td>

          <?php } ?>

            </tr>

      <?php } ?>

     </tbody>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="upload" name="upload" />
    </table>
</form>
```

The form above have a table which tr and td is dynamic in sense that i used php code to loop the input text and the value in it is like rownumber dash columnnumber now. I want the on submit to see the one full column textbox value. So in server script i will need,
PHP CODE IS

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
   print_r($_POST['columnVal0']);
   exit();
}
```

so the output should be array with all first column values which is 0-0,1-0,2-0.... 101-0 right?
but the problem is i get half of values. e.g 0-0,0-1,0-2 upto 45-0 only. 
Some How i feel its max_input_var problem but i am not sure and if you think its really that problem kindly inform me how to solve it, although i used ini_set('max_input_vars', '9999'); but its not work. And also kindly inform me if you know how to assign an array the size of ram or how to know the size of an array (in MB).
I know its a bit complex problem but i hope somebody will get my question and help me solve it! Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I have just improved it a little bit for the sake of readibility:

HTML form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="f">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
      <?php 
        for ($a = 0; $a < 101; $a++) { 
            echo '<tr>';

            for ($b = 0; $b <= 20; $b++) { 
                echo '<td>
                        <input type="text" name="columnVal'.$b.'[]" value="'.$a.'-'.$b.'" />
                      </td>';
            }

            echo '</tr>';

        } 
      ?>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="upload" name="upload" />
    </table>
</form>
```

Form action:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
       print_r($_POST['columnVal0']);
       exit();
    }
?>
```

As first attempt, I got the same error message as yours, i.e. max_input_var which was a commented directive in php.ini and set at 1000. Please, uncomment it and set it to the value you need.
In this way, you get the full column list you expect:

```
Array ( [0] => 0-0 [1] => 1-0 [2] => 2-0 [3] => 3-0 [4] => 4-0 [5] => 5-0 [6] => 6-0 [7] => 7-0 [8] => 8-0 [9] => 9-0 [10] => 10-0 [11] => 11-0 [12] => 12-0 [13] => 13-0 [14] => 14-0 [15] => 15-0 [16] => 16-0 [17] => 17-0 [18] => 18-0 [19] => 19-0 [20] => 20-0 [21] => 21-0 [22] => 22-0 [23] => 23-0 [24] => 24-0 [25] => 25-0 [26] => 26-0 [27] => 27-0 [28] => 28-0 [29] => 29-0 [30] => 30-0 [31] => 31-0 [32] => 32-0 [33] => 33-0 [34] => 34-0 [35] => 35-0 [36] => 36-0 [37] => 37-0 [38] => 38-0 [39] => 39-0 [40] => 40-0 [41] => 41-0 [42] => 42-0 [43] => 43-0 [44] => 44-0 [45] => 45-0 [46] => 46-0 [47] => 47-0 [48] => 48-0 [49] => 49-0 [50] => 50-0 [51] => 51-0 [52] => 52-0 [53] => 53-0 [54] => 54-0 [55] => 55-0 [56] => 56-0 [57] => 57-0 [58] => 58-0 [59] => 59-0 [60] => 60-0 [61] => 61-0 [62] => 62-0 [63] => 63-0 [64] => 64-0 [65] => 65-0 [66] => 66-0 [67] => 67-0 [68] => 68-0 [69] => 69-0 [70] => 70-0 [71] => 71-0 [72] => 72-0 [73] => 73-0 [74] => 74-0 [75] => 75-0 [76] => 76-0 [77] => 77-0 [78] => 78-0 [79] => 79-0 [80] => 80-0 [81] => 81-0 [82] => 82-0 [83] => 83-0 [84] => 84-0 [85] => 85-0 [86] => 86-0 [87] => 87-0 [88] => 88-0 [89] => 89-0 [90] => 90-0 [91] => 91-0 [92] => 92-0 [93] => 93-0 [94] => 94-0 [95] => 95-0 [96] => 96-0 [97] => 97-0 [98] => 98-0 [99] => 99-0 [100] => 100-0 )
```

For array size in MB, the best answers I was able to find are reported here: [php get array's data size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018651/php-get-arrays-data-size) and https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: max_input_var which was a commented directive in php.ini. Please, uncomment it and set it to the value you need, how ???? the problem is i search alot different technique but non work and even tho i could not find php.ini in my cpanel

Comment: I suppose your project has been already hosted on a web space.
In this case, you might or might not have full access to the php.ini. This is up to your hosting provider.
In case you don't find a link to php.ini, you have to contact the technical support (open a ticket) and ask for php.ini modification in that directive.

If you are working locally, i.e. using XAMPP on laptop/PC, then follow this C:/xampp/php/php.ini and modify the directive.

Anyway, I strongly suggest you to change your mind replacing 2000 input fields with buttons. This could be a good workaround.